# JSpinner in JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jspinner

I need to put a JSpinner in a JOptionPane. Here is what I've tried:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpinnerNumberModel sModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 30, 1);
        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(sModel);
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(spinner);
    }
```

Which results in:

[image]

How do I remove the textbox?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use `showMessageDialog`.

```
SpinnerNumberModel sModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 30, 1);
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(sModel);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, spinner);
```

For still having a cancel button, use:

```
int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, spinner, "Enter valid number", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
if (option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
{
    // user hit cancel
} else if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
{
    // user entered a number
}
```

Here is a screenshot on OS X:

[image]

Comment: @MartjinCourteaux Thank you. Would it be possible to add text too (like "Please enter a valid number:", or do I need to use a JPanel for that?

Comment: Two options for adding text: Set it as Dialog title, or add (as you already pointed out) a JPanel with the two components: the label and the spinner.

Comment: @MartjinCourteaux ok. One more thing - I still need the cancel button. What do you suggest?